# what does container prop do in the Drawer component in material-ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am reading the official document of material-ui's `Drawer` component, and I found a `container` prop and I do not have an idea where it comes from. It is not mentioned in its API documentation. Is this one of the built-in react component's props?

Below is a screenshot of the responsive drawer component from material-ui: https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/#responsive-drawer

[image]

Comment: I did not found any container in the material UI and where did you found this screenshot? please give use the exact link

Comment: Hi @NishargShah, please go to 'responsive drawer' part via link https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/#responsive-drawer, and then click the '<>' button to show the source code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That prop is coming from the `Modal` props because `Drawer` includes props from `Modal` when `variant="temporary"`.

> container - HTML element | func
>
> An HTML element or function that returns one. The container will have
> the portal children appended to it. By default, it uses the body of
> the top-level document object, so it's simply document.

Modal Props: https://material-ui.com/api/modal/

Please check here https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/5cc1d0fc8756534f181d55af02a5a0d65b486603/packages/material-ui/src/Drawer/Drawer.d.ts#L11